# DX9 CreateTexture/CreateSprite/Present Freeze

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17, directx, directx-9

I use dx9 for a few small things here as I've gotten used to it and it does it's job pretty well, but lately I've been facing quite an issue that no matter how much I try look into, I can never find a solution for.
As the title states, I sometimes freeze the whole program and I'm forced to close it on calling CreateTexture, CreateSprite and sometimes from the device's Present which I can only guess stems from the last 2 ones. Thing is, there seems to be some kind of spots that whenever I try call any of the above functions for it freezes without fail, but without creating a texture at all and simply using a plain rectangle I'm 100% fine. I've tried going through all the memory pools of CreateTexture as it could perhaps been any of that but it still happens. For reference I call these functions like so

```
m_pDirect3DDevice->CreateTexture(m_nImageX, m_nImageY, 1, 0, D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8, D3DPOOL_MANAGED, &m_pNewTexture.m_pTexture, NULL);
D3DXCreateSprite(m_pDirect3DDevice, &m_pNewTexture.m_pSprite);
m_pDirect3DDevice->Present(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Any help or suggestions at all are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where are you checking for failed ``HRESULT`` values?  Are you creating a texture every frame of rendering? You should read [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d9/accurately-profiling-direct3d-api-calls). Generally creating resources is slow compared to just rendering, so creating a texture and a sprite every frame is going to be slow.

Comment: I am only creating them once, whenever I need to and then I store them and re-use them on many occasions, furthermore I don't do any device resetting so they don't get invalidated either